what is the best way to recognize embossed text with Tesseract OCR?
I am trying to read the text from a U.S. penny to orient the coin.
the original is from
https://www.usmint.gov/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/2024-lincoln-penny-uncirculated-obverse-philadelphia.jpg
I have extracted the word liberty, and am having difficulty with tesseract.

the code I am using is
def GetLibertyCroppedArea(img):
    # ll = 10,242
    # ur = 130,190
    top = 190
    bot = 240
    lft = 10
    rgt = 130
    cropped_area = img[top:bot, lft:rgt]
    cropped_area = cv2.resize(cropped_area, (360,150))
return cropped_area

def LoadImage(fn):
    img = cv2.imread(fn)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (400,400))
    return img

img = LoadImage(fn)
liberty = GetLibertyCroppedArea(rotated_image)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(liberty, config='--psm 8')
text = text.rstrip()
print(text)

I have tried various psm values without success
what preprocessing steps are necessary for tesseract to have a better chance of recognition ?
tesseract was installed from
https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/releases/download/v5.4.0.20240606/tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-5.4.0.20240606.exe
this is the actual image I am passing to tesseract

pytesseract.image_to_string(liberty, config='--psm 8')
returns "LOOGATY,"

what is the output you are getting? could you please share that?

tesseract is returning Bes’

Are you using your own tessdata or is it the default one coming from tesseract?

I am using whatever came with tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-5.4.0.20240606.exe from github

I got it, now I will post the answer, I was looking for few details to answer

The issue is not in the code, but the tessdata file. As core of tesseract is in the tessdata, I would suggest you should train your own tessdata with the respective font on your input and use it.
You can refer use this tessdata file: tessdata
Rename it as eng.traineddata amd replace that with the default one in tessdata folder
with your code and the attached file, I got the below output,
LIBERTY

NOTE: If you are using windows, then tessdata would be at C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract OCR\tessdata or C:\Program Files\Tesseract OCR\tessdata depending upon your installation. replace the default eng.traineddata with the file mentioned the link mrz.traineddata. The rename mrz.traineddata to eng.traineddata
After using the code provided in question with the traineddata mentioned in link(follow the rename steps in NOTES), it is working fine.
import pytesseract
import cv2

tesseract_path=r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = tesseract_path


def GetLibertyCroppedArea(img):
    # ll = 10,242
    # ur = 130,190
    top = 190
    bot = 240
    lft = 10
    rgt = 130
    cropped_area = img[top:bot, lft:rgt]
    cropped_area = cv2.resize(cropped_area, (360,150))

    return cropped_area

def LoadImage(fn):
    img = cv2.imread(fn)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (400,400))
    return img

img = LoadImage('2024-lincoln-penny-uncirculated-obverse-philadelphia.jpg')
liberty = GetLibertyCroppedArea(img)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(liberty, config='--psm 8')
text = text.rstrip()
print(text)

OUTPUT:
LIBERTY


Thank you for the response. I tried using your mrz.traineddata file, but I get IEEER07

Rename it as eng.traineddata amd replace that with the default one. It works.

I tried your rename idea, but no luck. I still get IEEER07.  I removed python and ran tesseract directly with "\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe" image_passed_to_tesseract.jpg out --psm 8.  Please confirm you posted the correct tessdata file, or provide the steps you used to create it.

@skeeter updated my answer with steps available in NOTES. You can run with python or direct it does not matter once you replace the default traineddata with the file available at link. Please keep posted

what are the steps that you used to create the traineddata file ?

is the mentioned steps working in your machine?

no. the latest file will not let tesseract load: Error opening data file C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR/tessdata/eng.traineddata

could you share the command you used

"\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe" image_passed_to_tesseract.jpg out --psm 8

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
